# UUID issue with passport Laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I want to use UUID in Laravel passport instead of the default id in my laravel project.

I changed all the `user_id` and `client_id` columns to uuid in the migrations and i add `Passport::ignoreMigrations()` in the register method in `AppServiceProvider`.

When i tested in postman by creating a new raw in users table, i get in my response the token but when i use this token in a secured route i always get response status:

```
401 Unauthorized and in the response body message:Unauthenticated.
```

Comment: No, i'm not using a 3rd party package

Comment: take a look at this https://mlo.io/blog/2018/08/17/laravel-passport-uuid/

Comment: i tried before i share with you my issue ! didn't work but thank you anyway @veelasky

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 4):

things I did to correct this problem:

1. in `AppServiceProvider` and `register` function add:

```php
Passport::ignoreMigrations()
```

2. run `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-migrations`
3. in `CreateOauthAuthCodesTable` change to

```php
$table->uuid('id');
$table->primary('id');
$table->uuid('user_id')->index();
```

> so on other passport tables and migrations

4. in appServiceProvider and boot method add below code:

```php
use Laravel\Passport\Client;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

Client::creating(function (Client $client) {
    $client->incrementing = false;
    $client->id = \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
});

Client::retrieved(function (Client $client) {
    $client->incrementing = false;
});
```

6. then I migrate my tables with `php artisan migrate:fresh` (Alert: **This command will delete all current tables of database**)
7. the key note is don't forget to add

```php
protected $primaryKey = 'Id'; // in my case I capitalize id to Id
```

there you are!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me, one change I did make was I added the creating/retrieved changes to the boot method of the model (in my case, a trait as Uuid is used on every model, and then added that trait to a `BaseModel` class which all my models extend. This prevented me from congestion AppServiceProvider too much. Cheers for your help

Comment: It's my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

```
php artisan passport:install --uuids
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change the `user_id` in `oauth_access_tokens` to `uuid` type, follow this steps:

Create one migration to alter the table `oauth_access_tokens`:
`php artisan make:migration alter_table_oauth_access_tokens`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('oauth_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('user_id');
    });
    Schema::table('oauth_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('user_id')->index()->nullable();
    });
}
```

Comment: this still works now